# Swift - error with results after using searchbar

Tags: swift, xcode, uisearchbar

I have little bit problem with my search bar. As you see on screens. When I dont filter anything and i click on first, it shows me first detail screen, when I click on second, it shows me second screen with detail, but when I filter something for example second (like in last screen) and click on result, it shows me first screen, which is wrong, I want to see second screen with detail. My code is here:

```
import UIKit

    //array definiton
    var names = [String]()
    var namesDesc = [String]()
    var namesDescWhereTo = [String]()
    var imageArr = [UIImage(named: "Alobal")!,UIImage(named: "Akumulátory")!,UIImage(named: "Akvária")!,UIImage(named: "Autovrak")!,UIImage(named:                  "Autosklo")!]
    var myIndex = 0


class mainTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    //definition variables for VC
    var namesTableView = names
    var filteredNames = [String]()
    var searchController : UISearchController!
    var resultsController = UITableViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //load file with names - names.txt
        do {
            //definice názvu souboru + oddělovače
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "names", ofType: "txt"){
                let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                names = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            //pokud je nějaký error
            print(err)
        }

        //load file with descriptions - namesDesc.txt
        do {
            //definice názvu souboru + oddělovače
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "namesDesc", ofType: "txt"){
                let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                namesDesc = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            //pokud je nějaký error
            print(err)
        }

        //load file with information "where to" - namesDescWhereTo.txt
        do {
            //definice názvu souboru + oddělovače
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "namesDescWhereTo", ofType: "txt"){
                let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                namesDescWhereTo = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            //pokud je nějaký error
            print(err)
        }


        namesTableView = names

        //definiton main title + call method setupNavBar()
        self.title = "Where to?"
        setupNavBar()


        self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }



    //method where I define large titles
    func setupNavBar() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.filteredNames = self.namesTableView.filter { (name:String) -> Bool in
            if name.lowercased().contains(self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        //reloading
        self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            return self.namesTableView.count
        } else {
            return self.filteredNames.count
        }
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        if tableView == self.tableView {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.namesTableView[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredNames[indexPath.row]
        }
            return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }

    }
```

[image: main screen]

[image: If I click first]

[image: If I click second]

[image: If I search second and click on result, it shows me first page]

Thanks for help.

Comment: you just use the hidden label for store the cell id like if first have a id number 1 and second's id is 2. when you click on the cell get the hidden label's value instead of Indexpath.row. it's just a trick

Answer (score 0):

In all your other datasource methods (`cellForRow`, `numberOfRows` etc), you did this:

```
if tableView == self.tableView {
    // use the normal data source array
} else {
    // use the filtered data source array
}
```

So why not do this in `prepareForSegue`, where you pass the item corresponding to `myIndex` to the next controller?

You don't have an instance of the `tableView` so you can't check whether the user is searching, can you?

Other than checking whether the passed in table view is the original table view, you can check the `isActive` property of `searchController`:

```
if searchController.isActive && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
    // use the filtered data
} else {
    // use the normal data
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Im beginner in this but i have question. Why I need prepareForSegue? I thought, that information for next VC is in this method `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myIndex = indexPath.row
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        }` Thanks

Comment: How are you passing which row is selected to the next vc? @KubikSukenik

Comment: I thought - `myIndex = indexPath.row`. In second VC i have this: `self.title = names[myIndex]
        recLabelDesc.text = namesDesc[myIndex]
        recLabelWhereTo.text = namesDescWhereTo[myIndex]`.

Comment: @KubikSukenik oh I didn't realise `myIndex` is a global variable. Do you are passing data with global variables. This is a bad practice. Your arrays and myIndex should be properties in the first VC. Shared mutable state can cause various mistakes. Try googling "pass data to VC with prepareForSegue". Use that and pass the name, nameDesc, image and so on to the next cv. Remember to use the filtered array if the user is searching.

Answer (score 0):

@Sweeper I added prepareForSegue, but problem is same :( in the destination VC after filtering i cant see right results. This i add to main VC.

```
override func prepare(
for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any ? ) {
if segue.identifier == "segue" {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let resultName: String
        if isFiltering() {
            resultName = filteredNames[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            resultName = namesTableView[indexPath.row]
        }
        let controller = segue.destination as!ViewController
        controller.test = resultName
    }
}}
```

And this I have in destination VC in viewDidLoad():

```
title = test
recLabelDesc.text = test
```